# python-requests does not grab JSESSIONID

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, cookies, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a website using requests. However, a post method that I need to use requires the headers below. I can fill everything apart from the JSESSION ID. The only way I can get this post method to work is if I manually go into the browser, start a session and inspect the page to retrieve the JSESSIONID.

I am looking for a way to retrieve this JSESSIONID using the requests package in python. I saw some suggestions for using a session. However, the requests session does not grab the JSESSIONID, which is the only thing I need. How should I go about a possible solution?

```
Host: 
Connection: 
Content-Length:
Accept: 
X-Requested-With: 
User-Agent: 
Content-Type:
Sec-GPC: 
Origin: 
Sec-Fetch-Site: 
Sec-Fetch-Mode: 
Sec-Fetch-Dest: 
Referer: 
Accept-Encoding:
Accept-Language: 
Cookie: _1aa19=; JSESSIONID=;
```

What I currently tried is use a session from the requests package, which should store the cookies of the session. However, After I use a .get method requests.cookies does not have the JSESSIONID stored

```
query = 'Example%20query'
s = requests.Session()
suggest = s.get(f'https://www.examplewebsite.nl/api_route/suggest?query={query}').json()
s.cookies
```

Comment: Do `_ = s.get('https://www.wozwaardeloket.nl')` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSESSIONID is generated when you go to `https://www.examplewebsite.nl` page first.

```
import requests


query = 'Example%20query'
s = requests.Session()
s.get('https://www.examplewebsite.nl')
suggest = s.get(f'https://www.examplewebsite.nl/api_route/suggest?query={query}').json()
print(s.cookies.get("JSESSIONID"))
```

Comment: Do you also have experience with cookies in scrapy? The solution now works well using the requests package. However, when migrating to scrapy I am now running into the issue that scrapy is retrieving the JSESSIONID